# What happened to the windows-forms tag?

Tags: support, tags

I just wanted to retag a question to windows-forms but apparaently this tag was deleted or renamed, I can only find winforms (42).

Did a retag go wrong?

Comment: On a second look the count for WinForms was 3484, so just a re-tag then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got fed up of fighting a losing battle against winforms. Most people call it winforms. Microsoft call it winforms. What the heck, it'll do.

If there is a mass revolt, it is trivial to change it back, but winforms seems to cause a *lot* less problems than windows-forms.

Comment: I get it. The main reason for asking was that I saw it had just 42 questions, but that was a fluke.

Answer (score 1):

[windows-forms](/questions/tagged/windows-forms)  [was retagged to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11113/windows-forms-winforms/) [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) some time back.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11113/windows-forms-winforms/

Comment: Well, 13 hours...

Comment: Has it really been that long?